# Is there a way to simplify the qresource file descriptors?

Tags: qt, qml

I currently have a `qml.qrc` file that looks like this:

```
<RCC>
    <qresource prefix="/qml">
        <file>qml/components/Icon.js</file>
        <file>qml/components/IconButton.qml</file>
        <file>qml/components/IconLabel.qml</file>
        <file>qml/main.qml</file>
        <file>qml/setup/NewProject.qml</file>
        <file>qml/setup/Setup.qml</file>
        <file>qml/setup/Startup.qml</file>
        <file>qml/workspace/AnimationWindow.qml</file>
        <file>qml/workspace/DepthChartControls.qml</file>
        <file>qml/workspace/NewAnimationWindow.qml</file>
        <file>qml/workspace/TraceWindow.qml</file>
        <file>qml/workspace/Workspace.qml</file>
        <file>qml/workspace/WorkspaceMenuBar.qml</file>
        <file>qml/Empty.qml</file>
        <file>qml/qmldir</file>
        <file>qml/Style.qml</file>
        <file>icons/play.svg</file>
    </qresource>
    <qresource prefix="/icons">
        <file>lib/material-design/icons/svg/play.svg</file>
    </qresource>
</RCC>
```

Which makes it so that I have to reference qml files like: `engine.load(QUrl("qrc:/qml/qml/main.qml"))`, and when I want to access the icon I have to specify `:/icons/lib/material-design/icons/svg/play.svg`. Is there a way that I can simplify the paths, by maybe restricting qresources to a prefixed directory path?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It already is the way you want it to be. You can access the files as

```
qrc:/qml/Icon.js
qrc:/icons/play.svg
```

etc.

Generally it works as follows: given

```
<qresource prefix="PREFIX">
<file alias="ALIAS">QRC_RELATIVE_FILEPATH</file>
</qresource>
```

the resource is accessed via

```
qrc:PREFIX/ALIAS
```

The default value for `ALIAS` is the filename (and only filename) from `QRC_RELATIVE_FILEPATH` - i.e. the use of the path elements in your example is superfluous, but supported.